# How to force an app icon on Android O? (Prevent the launcher from adapting it)

Tags: java, android, icons, launcher

*This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please bear with me if I fail to articulate my question.*

I am working on an Android app that targets Android O, and I want the launcher to NOT show the icon adapted i.e. remove the white background.
I tried to use adaptive icons and they work, but the problem is that they change the icon itself making it rouned, square, squircle and tear-shaped.

At first I thought it's out of my hands, but some other apps (facebook, whatsapp and snapchat for example) have their icons unchanged.

**tl;dr: How can I force an icon to be used by the launcher on Android O?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other apps you mention (Facebook, Whatsapp, and Snapchat) don't yet target Android O. Once they do, they'll also be forced to have an adaptive icon as well.

Comment: that being said, it looks like you could change your target sdk version to get the result you desire

Comment: @dazza5000 - given the [requirement to target API 26 by November 2018](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html), that is, at best, a temporary workaround.

Comment: hehehehe - i knew ian would protest :) it is good to be mindful of the api bump in november

Comment: But that would also deprive me of the perks of targeting API 26. Thanks for shedding light on that.

Comment: Yep, how launchers treat apps that target API 26 will be different (it isn't the system that forces the white background, but the launcher), but for the Google created launchers, you should assume an adaptive icon is a requirement for targeting API 26.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `targetSdkVersion` property from your app level `build.gradle` file. It will work.

Comment: Or just use a targetSdkVersion below 26 (maybe not ideal solution but it works)