# Android transparent launcher icon in Oreo

Tags: icons, android-studio-3.0, android-launcher, android-8.0-oreo

Android launcher icon with transparent background not working in Oreo. It shows a circle background. How can i remove this circle shaped background in Oreo Using Android Studio. In other versions, no problem. Any idea please help me

Just open this image for launcher icon without rounded shape https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IVpP.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force an app icon on Android O? (Prevent the launcher from adapting it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289269/how-to-force-an-app-icon-on-android-o-prevent-the-launcher-from-adapting-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a launcher icon a transparent background in Oreo, you have to target API 25 or lower. Keep in mind that all apps will be [required to target API 26+](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) by November 2018 (or August 2018 in the case of new apps).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Adaptive icons? According to this article on medium, the background drawable must be opaque, while the foreground icon can be transparent.

"background drawables must be opaque whilst foregrounds can contain transparency."

https://medium.com/google-developers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e

... possibly duplicate of: [Transparent adaptive icon background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722958/transparent-adaptive-icon-background)

Comment: Some apps show launcher icon without background shape. They does not use adaptive icons, just only ic_launcher with different dpis. i tried like this but shows a background shape. Just take a look this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IVpP.jpg @ Mathias Kirkegaard. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not helped me. Some apps show their icon without background shape. Just take a look  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IVpP.jpg. How they actually do this. They does not use Adaptive icon. Only ic_launcher with different dpis. Me checked their launcher and did like that but not working. Shows a rounded background on Oreo

Comment: I tried testing it as well, and i am afraid Oreo does it own black magic, forcing a process on the icon. Found this link, which states the icon needs to be circular for oreo: https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/android-8-oreo-process-home-screen-icon/ ... maybe you can archieve some transparency, if you can reproduce what he does in the last example (I tried with a small circular .png drawable, but I still get the background circle).