# I can't set an icon for my app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

So I imported all the images with the app icon in the mipmap folder and I deleted the round icon folder since I don't need/use any round icons for my app. Then, in the AndroidManifest.xml file I deleted the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`(again, I don't need/use round icons, that's why I deleted this line of code). And that's it, this is how I have been tought to add icons to an app, but when I test this in the Android Studio Virtual Machine, I still get the Android face icon, and I don't know why..
Any help?

This is the Icon I should get

[image]

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

[image]

This is the Icon I get (The FunFacts1 app!)

[image]

Comment: did you insert the icon manually or through the android tool?

Comment: checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application

Comment: If that is a 'Google Pixel' emulator, could you try with some other phone emulator please?  Round icons are forced in google pixel and you can't do much about it.  But even in that case, i would expect the actual app icon to appear round with white padding background.

Comment: @Andrew have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after some testing and research, I found the answer.

If you are targeting 26> (which you will have to do because of the [new requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) from the end of the month) your icon will be round, or it will have a round (container) around the icon.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51199485) is a discussion about this.

---

I would also advise you to look at [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive), which will now be the required way of setting icons.

By using adaptive icons you can set the background and foreground of your icons and set the shape for different devices:

[image]

The answer by [@InsaneCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323324/5550161) is correct, but it will be deprecated by the end of the month.

You will now have to create adaptive and legacy launcher icons, you can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-adaptive).

---

Last point, which is the most important - always refer to the official documentation as a lot of answers are deprecated and everyone answers just to get reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code into your manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@mipmap/icon_name" android:label="@string/app_name" >
.... 
</application>
```

and put ic_launcher in all folders according to icon size

```
mipmap-ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px
mipmap-mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px
mipmap-hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px
mipmap-xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px
mipmap-xxhdpi (480 dpi, Extra-extra-high density screen) - 144px x 144px
mipmap-xxxhdpi (640 dpi, Extra-extra-extra-high density screen) - 192px x 192px
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in you `AndroidMmanifest.xml` and than try to run it again and what happens.

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: First of all, I tried it, second of all, I told that I deleted this line of code because I don't use round icons... Anyways, it didn't work

Comment: but according to your icon name it will perfects to work for you.

Comment: Friend but that same situation i have created manually and than after i given the answer after execution and in my case it will working perfectly does you want to see the Screenshot?

Comment: I actually want to see it

Comment: @HB Sorry bro and forget about the icon it will never appear for you.

Answer (score 0):

In both places put the same image path:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

if another image you will use so simple paste on mipmap folder

Comment: So basically I added 'android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" ' this line of code. I did it and it's still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I actually found another way...
In Android Studio, right click on the app folder and select New-->Image Asset and there click the 3 button next to Path section and there drag and drop your image.